# Input falls outside of div header

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have this header and the input field goes outside of the header for some reason.
If you could help me understand why this happens that would be great.

```css
* {
  background-color: #e52165;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #0d1137;
  display: block;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10vh;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.subheader {}

.subHeader div,
.subheader {
  display: inline-block;
}

.banner img {
  display: block;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!--- Header and subheader --->
<header>
  <img alt="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
</header>
<div class="subHeader">
  <div>
    <a href="#"> Categorie A</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#"> Categorie B</a></div>
  <div><a href="#"> Categorie C</a></div>
  <div><a href="#"> Categorie D</a></div>
</div>
<!--- Main content --->
<main>
  <div class="banner">
    <img alt="banner" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: First thing I noticed is that your `img` tag is not closed

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. If you isnert code, please use the code snippet (ctrl + m) so it can be parsed/run. I edited your question this time and merged the code for you.

Comment: @Mr.Phantom `<img>` is an empty tag. As such, it does not need to be closed.

Comment: You've set a height on your header that's inadequate to contain the input and the space around it. What's your intended outcome? Please revise to make that more clear.

Comment: The editor of the post has closed it, it was like this when I looked at the post  ```<img alt="banner" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main Issue is with your `header` height. The content (child elements) within is more than `10vh`, that's why everything breaks.

You could fix it with `min-height:10vh;` on the header. Or simply set height to auto. Or simply let the `header` take it's height as per the child elements and do not explicitly set any height at all :)

```
header {
  background-color: #0d1137;
  display: block;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 10vh; /* This line */
}
```

**FULL CODE:**

```css
* {
  background-color: #e52165;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* Added this line */
}

body{ /* Added body nd CSS */
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw; 
}
header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #0d1137;
  display: block;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 10vh; /* This is the Issue */
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.subheader {}

.subHeader div,
.subheader {
  display: inline-block;
}

.banner img {
  display: block;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!--- Header and subheader --->
<header>
  <img alt="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
</header>
<div class="subHeader">
  <div>
    <a href="#"> Categorie A</a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#"> Categorie B</a></div>
  <div><a href="#"> Categorie C</a></div>
  <div><a href="#"> Categorie D</a></div>
</div>
<!--- Main content --->
<main>
  <div class="banner">
    <img alt="banner" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400">
  </div>
</main>
</body>
```